# Can't connect to mongo-express using docker stack

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to deploy a stack with mongo and mongo-express. I want both of them to be available from my host computer. That is to be able to connect to the mongo db and access the mongo-express web interface.

I have the following `stack.yml` :

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

The `mongo` instance is reachable from my host computer, but the web interface is not. It justs tries to connect forever.

Comment: May be you need to assign a volume attribute to mongo volumes:
        - mongo_volume:/data/db

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I can think of is more related to service startup order.

Try following operations

```
#>docker-compose  -f stack.yml up --no-start 
#>docker-compose -f stack.yml  start mongo
#>docker-compose -f stack.yml  start mongo-express
```

The main issue is that mongo-express is try to connect to mongo and at that time mongo was not completely started or ready to connect and that's why mongo-express quickly exited.

In order to specify order take a look at following articles.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on
https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/